# the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function sfml overriding draw

Tags: c++, constants, sfml

I'm using SFML 2.1 and want to override the drawable::draw method:

```
void AnimatedSprite::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
```

In its implementation, I'm using the a member function with the following signature: (the function that causes the title's error)

```
const sf::Sprite AnimatedSprite::getCurrent()
```

In this function I use another function with similar signature:

```
const sf::Sprite Animation::getCurrent()
```

where I return a non-const Sprite.

I guess it might be the problem, but why? Can't I use a non-const variable to draw my entity with? And if I can, how?

Comment: Did you forget to add const on the getCurrent function? Also you are returning a copy of the sprite, is that what you intended? Try `const sf::Sprite& AnimatedSprite::getCurrent() const`

Comment: it is working, edit it as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to add const on the getCurrent function? Also you are returning a copy of the sprite, is that what you intended? Try `const sf::Sprite& AnimatedSprite::getCurrent() const`